# C++ 3D Vector Template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm trying to create a Vector class using templates to store 3D positions of an object. I have created the class, but I am keep getting a error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Vector3::~Vector3(void)" (??1?$Vector3@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

It is something to do with me creating the Vector in the main function, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it... Here's my code:

```
//Vector3.h
template <typename T>
class Vector3
{
public:
    Vector3(T elemOne, T elemTwo, T elemThree);
    ~Vector3();

    void display();

protected:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};

//Vector3.cpp Constructor.
#include"Vector3.h"

template<typename T>
Vector3<T>::Vector3(T elemOne, T elemTwo, T elemThree)
{
    x = elemOne;
    y = elemTwo;
    z = elemThree;
}

template<typename T>
Vector3<T>::~Vector3()
{

}

template<typename T>
void Vector3<T>::display()
{
    cout << "X: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Y: " << y << endl;
    cout << "Z: " << z << endl;
}

//MainFrame.cpp
int main()
{
    Vector3<int> vec(10, 20, 30);

    cout << "Press any key to continue..." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help on finding out this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full definition of `Vector3`?

Comment: You need to show more code. The code you've shown doesn't seem to have a problem.

Comment: Do you have template code in the same (included) file as main, or do you have it in separate file?

Comment: Posted all the code in my project as requested. Sorry about that

Comment: @vyktor I had a separate file called MainFrame which only contain the main function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Templates need to be defined in the same compilation unit in which they are used. You cannot place the implementation of a template in a different file as you have shown in your code.

I will also note that as it stands now, you don't need a destructor. You're not doing anything in it and it is not virtual, so it may be omitted to allow the compiler to generate one for you.

Comment: ahh... So just to make sure, you mean that whenever I use templates, both declaration and implementations will NEED to be in the same file??

Comment: Yes, or included from another file. I often place the code inline in the template class. I have seen some people place it in another file (`Vector3.tpp`, for example) and `#include` it from the header which defines the template class (`Vector3.h`).

Comment: the reason for that is that if the compiler wanted to compile each possible template definition, we'd get huge amounts of compiled object files. Just consider ``template<int N>`` : the compiler would have to compile ``2^32-1`` times the same class, which would take forever and fill you HD with object files. Therefore the templates cannot be precompiled into static libraries: whoever includes it has to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you don’t want to include the definitions of your `Vector` member functions in `Vector.cpp`, and should move them to `Vector.h`. The long answer is that a template *is not* a class: it is a *template* by which a class is constructed. Thus the definitions of the template must be available in the compilation unit (source file) that includes `Vector.h`.

A common solution if you want to keep things separate is to make, say, `VectorImpl.h`:

```
// VectorImpl.h

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(T x, T y, T z) { ... }
```

And include it from `Vector.h`, like so:

```
// Vector.h

#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

template<class T>
class Vector { ... };

#include "VectorImpl.h"

#endif
```

There *are* circumstances in which you *would* want to have a `Vector.cpp`: in particular, if you wanted to restrict `Vector` to just a few types, you would instantiate `Vector` with those types explicitly in `Vector.cpp`:

```
template class Vector<double>;
```

This allows you to create, for example, libraries of precompiled templates. However, for your purposes, you can just stick to the usual header-only solution.